# how to get the id of a checkbox inside an Adapter when it's checked?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I'm trying to implement a checkbox inside a list view. The listView has been generated from a JSON. In my Adapter when I call `onCheckedChanged`I want to get the id of that checkbox and then return it back to the server. what if I want to set an id to a checkbox with my own constructor?

```
public class CheckListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
List List =new ArrayList();
SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
boolean[] itemChecked;
    public CheckListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
        itemChecked = new boolean[10];
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(10);
     }



public void add(@Nullable checkListItems object) {
    super.add(object);
    List.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return List.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return List.get(position);

}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
  View row;
  row = convertView;
 final checkListItemHolder h;
  if  ( row == null){
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_checklist,parent,false);
      h = new checkListItemHolder();
      h.tx_itemNo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.checkListItemNO);
      h.tx_name= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.checkListItemName);
      h.checkBoxLab= (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);



      row.setTag(h);
  }
   else
   {
     h = (checkListItemHolder)row.getTag();
  }

     checkListItems L= (checkListItems)this.getItem(position);
     h.tx_name.setText(L.getItemName());
     Log.w("inja to adaptor","ta inja");
     h.tx_itemNo.setText(L.getItemNo());

 //    h.checkBoxLab.setChecked(false);
//     h.checkBoxLab.setChecked(checkedHolder[position]);
h.checkBoxLab.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          //  checkedHolder[position] = isChecked;
           Log.w("yahoo","yahoo");

    }
});


     return row;

}

public boolean isChecked(int position) {
    return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
}

public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
    mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

}

public void toggle(int position) {
    setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

}
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                             boolean isChecked) {

    mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

}

public boolean[] checkedHolder;

private void createCheckedHolder() {
    checkedHolder = new boolean[getCount()];
}


static class checkListItemHolder{

        TextView tx_name, tx_itemNo;
        CheckBox checkBoxLab;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line  `h.checkBoxLab.setTag(position)` under this line `h.checkBoxLab= (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);`
use this to delete the row from your list view :

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                             boolean isChecked) {
    Integer index = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    List.remove(index.intValue());  
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

and please explain what exactly do you want to return to server ?

Comment: I don't want to delete the row. I need to get the id of the checked box

Comment: if your objects in the List you have, contains the id you want you can access that by using `List.get(index.intValue()).getID() ` . if you want to set id to the checkbox you can use `h.checkbox.setId(int);` and then in onCheckChanged : `buttonView.getId();`  .  If these are not the answers you were looking for, please explain more about your problem.

Comment: I tried  this  ` if (isChecked) {
                    Integer index = (Integer) buttonView.getId();
                    Log.w("yahoo",""+index);
                }'  but index is zero for all check boxes.

Comment: @HadiSamadbin have you set the checkbox ids before using getId()?

Comment: yep like this 
        `checkListItems L= (checkListItems)this.getItem(position);`
         `h.tx_name.setText(L.getItemName());`
      
         `h.tx_itemNo.setText(L.getItemNo());`
         `h.checkBoxLab.setId(L.getItemNoint());`

Comment: please log the L.getItemNoint() value (instead of strings you are logging : "here in adapter", "to here") to see if it has the correct value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173707/discussion-between-fatemeh-fallahi-arezoudar-and-hadi-samadbin).

Comment: I'm trying to set the same id which I have received from Json. I defined `getItemNoint` in my constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `buttonView.getId()` inside onCheckedChanged method to get id of the checkbox. This view always refers to the checkbox whose check status has changed as said by [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener).